# Tridion: Replacement for Query.QueryOperator method?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

**Query.QueryOperator.AND_Field** 
We were using this method in Tridion R5.3 VBscript templates and it worked well. 
Recently , while migrating to Tridion 2011 SP1, we tried using this method, but it doesn't works.
We understood that this method is depreciated in new tridion versions.

As per some posts in Forum, we also enabled the following lines in CD_Storage_Conf:

```
<SearchFilter Name="SearchFilter" Class="com.tridion.broker.components.meta.MsSqlSearchFilterHome" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/> 
<Item typeMapping="Query" storageId="defaultdb"/>
```

The question is, what is replacement of the 'Query.QueryOperator.AND_Field' method? How can we use this filter in C# ?
How to use the Broker Querying Mechanism mentioned in the support API files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SDL Tridion 2011 Content Delivery, you create a `Query` object and add a `Criteria` object to it using the `setCriteria` method. The `Query` object accepts one Criteria object **ONLY**, but that `Criteria` object can in turn reference other `Criteria` objects in a tree structure.

For a good example of creating a Query filter using both AND and OR operators, see [Creating a filter](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_0AB6D192D7AB4EC18892631F519EF1DD) in the SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 documentation in SDL LiveContent.

```cs
// Schema has ID of either 511 (Article) or 34 (Press Release).
ItemSchemaCriteria IsArticle = new ItemSchemaCriteria(511);
ItemSchemaCriteria IsPressRelease = new ItemSchemaCriteria(34);
Criteria IsArticleOrPressRelease = CriteriaFactory.Or(IsArticle, IsPressRelease);

// Type of the item is 16 (Component).
ItemTypeCriteria IsComponent = new ItemTypeCriteria(16);

// Both of the above conditions must be true
Criteria AllCriteria = CriteriaFactory.And(IsArticleOrPressRelease, IsComponent);

// Add these criteria to a query
Query MyQuery = new Query();
MyQuery.Criteria = AllCriteria;
```

Comment: Hi David, Can you please let me know to which namespace does the Query class belongs?
We can either use Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query;
orTridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Filters;
But the later one is obsolete ? I tried using the first one, but not able to find the method SetCriteria.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Huston. It'll definitely be Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query. It's setCriteria in the Java API. Maybe the example in LiveContent is slightly wrong? Looking at the CHM documentation (Content Delivery ASP.NET API.chm) it shows a Criteria property that allows setting as well as getting. Can you try that?

Comment: Huston. I just tested and it is indeed MyQuery.Criteria = AllCriteria;

Answer updated and a comment left in LiveContent

Comment: This is working well so far. I am stuck at a point.
What is the equivalent of Query.AddSelectString() method?
Can I use CustomMetaValueCriteria for this?

Comment: What were you previously using the AddSelectString() method for? Can you share some code?

Comment: Hi David,
This is the a piece of Sample VBScript code where AddSelectString() is used to query the DB:

query1.AddOperator(Query.QueryOperator.AND_Field);
    query1.AddSelectString("item_reference_id in (select item_reference_id from items where initial_publication_date between '" + dtStartDate1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' and '" + dtEndDate1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "')");

Also, what is replacement for Query.Match and SearchFilter Classs?
Many Thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like you're searching for items first published between two dates. The Criteria objects you would use for this in SDL Tridion 2011 Content Delivery would be ItemInitialPublishDateCriteria objects.

Generally, you should avoid using the AddSelectString() method, because while SDL make best efforts to make Tridion's APIs backwards compatible the format of the databases it uses may change. Also, it keeps your code database agnostic.

Comment: Hi David, I am trying to use this code for the DB query I mentioned above :
********************************************************
CustomMetaDateRangeCriteria cmDateRange = new CustomMetaDateRangeCriteria("ItemInitialPublicationDate", dtStartDate1, dtEndDate1);
mainCriteria =CriteriaFactory.And(mainCriteria, cmDateRange);
*************************************************************

This however gives results only when I remove 'ItemInitialPublicationDate' from CustomMetaDateRangeCriteria. i.e CustomMetaDateRangeCriteria works with 2 dates, but I cant specify the Field name?

Comment: The initial publication date is not custom metadata, it is system metadata. ItemInitialPublishDate is not a field, it is a Criteria object. Please re-read my answer, the online documentation and the helpfiles. Use: Criteria initiallyPublishedAfterDate = new ItemInitialPublishDateCriteria(startDate, Criteria.GreaterThanOrEqual); Criteria initiallyPublishedBeforeDate = new ItemInitialPublishDateCriteria(endDate, Criteria.LessThanOrEqual); Criteria initiallyPublishedBetweenDates = CriteriaFactory.And(initiallyPublishedAfterDate, initiallyPublishedBeforeDate);. Combine this AndCriteria with others