# Tridion Filter : replacement for SetCustomMetaQuery

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

What is the replacement for SetCustomMetaQuery in Broker query Mechanism (Tridion 2011)?
I got lots of help through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390664/tridion-replacement-for-query-queryoperator-method) posted by me earlier.

for

```cs
query.SetCustomMetaQuery("KEY_NAME='Key' AND KEY_STRING_VALUE >= 'Yes'");
```

I tried

```cs
CustomMetaValueCriteria criteria1 = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("Key"), "Yes");
mainCriteria =CriteriaFactory.And(mainCriteria, criteria1);
query.Criteria = mainCriteria;
```

But I am stuck at below two examples in one of the filter CTs.

```cs
query.SetCustomMetaQuery("(((KEY_NAME='EventStartDate' AND 
KEY_DATE_VALUE >= '" + lowerDate + "')) or
((KEY_NAME='EventEndDate' AND KEY_DATE_VALUE >= '" + lowerDate + "')))"")
```

and

```cs
query.SetCustomMetaQuery("KEY_NAME = 'Publication_Issue_Date' and 
((convert(varchar(10), key_date_value, 101) = convert(varchar(10), 
cast('" + sIssueDate + "' as datetime), 101)) or
key_string_value like '%" + dtIssue[%=nNumber%].Year + "-0" + dtIssue[%=nNumber%].Month + "-" + dDay[%=nNumber%] + "%')");
```

Could any please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought I'd have a stab at this so could be way off!

How's this for the first example:

```
CustomMetaValueCriteria criteria1 = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("EventStartDate"), lowerDate, Criteria.GreaterThanOrEqual);
CustomMetaValueCriteria criteria2 = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("EventEndDate"), lowerDate, Criteria.GreaterThanOrEqual);

OrCriteria or = new OrCriteria(criteria1, criteria2);
```

Assumes that "lowerDate" is a DateTime.

The second one is a bit confusing, it looks like its checking for the existence of "Publication_Issue_Date" and any KEY_DATE_VALE that equals the **sIssueDate** variable **OR** that there's a string metadata value in the from of a date. So is that going to be something like?

```
CustomMetaKeyCriteria criteria1 = new CustomMetaKeyCriteria ("Publication_Issue_Date")
CustomMetaValueCriteria criteria2 = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(sIssueDate);
AndCriteria andCriteria = new AndCriteria(criteria1, criteria2);

string dt = dtIssue[%=nNumber%].Year + "-0" + dtIssue[%=nNumber%].Month + "-" + dDay[%=nNumber%];
CustomMetaValueCriteria criteria3 = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(dt, Criteria.Like)

OrCriteria or = new OrCriteria(andCriteria, criteria3);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Please try with:

```
CustomMetaValueCriteria criteria1 = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("Key"), "Yes", Criteria.GreaterThanOrEqual);
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have already tired this for first piece of code sample...and this works fine...
I want help with last 2 code samples...could you please help?